# Configure public files path in eslint

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I got the following files hierarchy

```
->public
  ->css
  ->javascript
->src
  ->views
app.js
```

I configured the path of public files in app.js like that

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.set('views', './src/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

After this I made a script and include it in my index.ejs (located in view)

```
...
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
    <body onload="resize()" onresize="resize()">
...
```

Everything work just fine, but eslint warns me about resize not being defined. How do I tell eslint where are my public files?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how to configure eslint to read the javascript from the public directory, but whenever I have had to do something like this I add the object I am using from another file as a global. (https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals) So I would add something like `/* global resize */`.